# Qt layout adds unnecessary space

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qt4

I'm creating a calender app and I finished the view widget for an appointment, which is basically a collection of `QLabels`.

[image]

It works like a charm, but I have a problem with the layout of the last 3 lines.
Every line is a `QHBoxLayout` and they are grouped in a `QVBoxLayout`.

I want the widgets in each `QHBoxLayout` to be aligned to the left (which they are standard) but there is this waste of space. Is there a way of contracting the space of the QHBoxLayout to the size of the widgets? And keeping in that size even if the window stretches?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Set alignment](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qlayout.html#setAlignment-2) for layout:

```
hboxLayout->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);
```

Comment: This worked great! I tried setting the ´Qt::AlignLeft´ in each widget I added but that didn't work earlier. Seems setting the layout alignment fixed it all. Awesome.

Answer (score 0):

```
QHBoxLayout* pLayout = new QHBoxLayout();<br />
//add your labels<br />
pLayout ->addItem(new QSpacerItem(40, 20, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Minimum));
```